# Consider committing to the Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange proposal

Tags: discussion

The [Cognitive Sciences](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2149/cognitive-sciences) proposal on Area 51 is *almost* launched. I've committed myself and we could use just a couple more *subject matter experts* or *people with many, relevant questions* to the greater field.

Since the Cognitive Sciences, especially Cognitive Psychology and Cognitive Ergonomics are extremely important to HCI and UX I thought some other users might be interested/proficient enough to join.

Don't join if you don't have questions/answers/a good knowledge of the subject due to the limit number of seats. If anyone has questions they would like posed on Cognitive Science.SE in it's private beta I would be more than happy to ask on your behalf.

Comment: Ben, I would like to know if you have similar postings on other sites. Else I would like us to carry forward, incl. on englishSE and writersSE, where I usually hang around.

Comment: @Kris I posted on UX.SE because I thought it was directly relevant and I know a few of us have mentioned the proposal. Go ahead and post on English.SE and Writers.SE if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cognitive Sciences site is now in private beta! No more users can join until the beta is public.

Please consider the questions [How to handle the overlap with Cognitive Science](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/691/how-to-handle-the-overlap-with-cognitive-science) and [Post questions you want asked on Cognitive Science.Stack Exchange](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/post-questions-you-want-asked-on-cognitive-science-stack-exchange)