# How to handle the overlap with Cognitive Science?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Cognitive Science private beta](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com) has just started. I would imagine [there will be an overlap](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/669/consider-committing-to-the-cognitive-sciences-stack-exchange-proposal) with this new site. How will we handle this overlap?

Can we draw a line what is out of scope here and better refer to Cognitive Science?

P.s.: I started [a similar topic on Cognitive Science](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-about-human-computer-interaction-hci-research-on-or-off-topic).

Comment: I'm keeping this question open until CGS goes into public beta so everybody gets a chance of checking it out and have better judgement.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's productive to fret over putting every question in the right bucket. When a cog-sci oriented question is asked here, we should evaluate it the same way we did before that site was created. If it doesn't fit here, we then have a separate decision of whether it should be migrated or simply closed. (Of course, the same applies to UX oriented questions on Cognitive Science.)

Comment: If there's a question that fits here, but would have been awesome on the Cognitive Science site, I'm okay with migrating for the purpose of helping that site along. :)

Comment: I disagree with your point in the comment; such questions should be asked on BOTH sites IMO. Just like business logic questions (though holy-war-ish) are relevant on both DBA and Programmers I feel double scoped questions should exist on both sites.

Comment: @BenBrocka: As the current SE system works, I don't feel posting the same question on both sites is helpful. You might find [this relating proposal I did on meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90475/157047) interesting.

Comment: @StevenJeuris asking the same exact question is not always helpful but some questions can be reworded to match the different audiences. That is what I think should be done.

Comment: @BenBrocka: To that I agree. I didn't quite get that from your wording.

Answer (score 4):

My feeling is that there is a division between the sites in most cases, because UX should relate to application design questions ( in a very broad way ) whereas CS should handle scientific or theoretical questions.

In my time here, I think there have been a few - very few - questions that really overlap. What is probably more useful is for members here who have interest or knowledge to join CS, and vv, so that UX questions can also have CS insights, and CS questions can, where relevant, also have UX insights.